# Bundler install gem not in root of repository from github

Tags: ruby, github, bundler

I want to install this gem https://github.com/datamapper/do/tree/master/do_oracle the problem is that as you can see it's not in the root of the repository, so using bundler with git option doesnt work, is there another way to install this gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to install this gem, add the following line to `Gemfile`:

```
gem "do_oracle", "~> 0.10.8"
```

However, if you want to install it from a git repo, then you have no luck - currently bundler doesn't support specifying path for git repos (this feature still remains a open issue. See [#396](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/396) on Github for more information).

A possible workaround is to fork it and move the gem to the root.

Comment: I want to install edge version, that wouldnt install edge version or would it?

Comment: @ryudice it would not, so you need to fork this repo to bring it to the root.